# What are the possible values for the "when" entry in view contribution points in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[Contributing an own view](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributesviews) in the explorer or debug view in vscode is pretty simple. However, I wonder what values can be used for the `when` field for a view. I couldn't find any useful information, but probably haven't found a good word combination to lead me to a description. Can anyone point me to the documentation for this field or can give a list with descriptions of the possible values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a list of options in the keybindings doc at: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts.